# Javascript regular expression fails when word starts with the danish character æ, ø, å

Tags: javascript, regex, character

I have a script on my site that highlights divs that contain words that is searched for through a input text field. It fails whenever i search for a word that starts with æ, ø and å (which are danish characters), but not if they are in anywhere else in the word.

I have made a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Y3cM/

```
rx = new RegExp("\\b(" + quest.join("|") + ")", "gi")
```

If you search for hello you can see that it highlights the first 2 divs, as they both contain hello. But if you search for "ælle", it does not highlight the containing div.

Hope that someone has a solution for this- Thankyou in advance! (:

Comment: I can't get your fiddle working but try using your regexp in conjunction with `\W` if you havent tried it already :)

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Did you press the search button, instead of just enter? I've just realized it doesn't word with enter.

How would that look in the regexp?

Comment: Word boundary `\b` is defined based on `\w`, which only considers character in US-ASCII (to be exact `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`). JS regex has virtually no support for Unicode, except for the crazy and tedious character range.

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen i just sucked, it works as expected.

Comment: @nhahtdh is correct about the `\b` ASCII based behaviour, the weird thing is it does also not find "Ælle" after removing the wordboundary from the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
rx = new RegExp("(^\|[ \n\r\t.,'\"\+!?-]+)(" + quest.join("|") + ")([ \n\r\t.,'\"\+!?-]+\|$)", "gi"),
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y3cM/15/

Thanks to [Source](http://breakthebit.org/post/3446894238/word-boundaries-in-javascripts-regular-expressions)

Comment: With this solution it only works when searching for one word for some reason? :s

Comment: Redundancy removed: `"(^|[ \n\r\t.,'\"+!?-]+)(" + quest.join("|") + ")([ \n\r\t.,'\"+!?-]+|$)"`. It only works when search for 1 word, since it is eating up the space character between words. Use look-ahead to avoid consuming the string: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y3cM/17/

Comment: That's almost it! Now there just "word boundary" on the other side. I would like it so that if i just type "Hello stack", the second container would still be highlighted.

Comment: And that was of course an easy fix. Went with your solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not regexp, this is how you process your rows. This works:

```
$("#search-question-button").click(function () {
    var quest = $('#search-questions-field').val().trim().split(" "),
    rx = new RegExp('\\b(' + quest.join("|") + ')', "gi");
    $(".searchin").removeClass('search-successful').addClass(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(rx) ? 'search-successful' : '';
    });
});
```

I used `match` instead of `replace`.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/8Y3cM/21/

Comment: Hello world should only highlighted "hello world", not "hello stackoverflow". And also if you type "lle" the last one is highlighted.

Comment: Then why do you use `quest.join("|")` after splitting by space?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting RegEx-issues aside, why do you even need RegEx for this? I think [a simple `.indexOf` will do fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y3cM/20/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-question-button").click(function () {
        var quest = $('#search-questions-field').val().trim().split(" ").map(function(q){return q.toLowerCase();});

        $(".searchin").each(function() {            
            elm = $(this);
            elm.removeClass('search-successful');
            found = 0;
            var t = elm.text().toLowerCase();
            quest.forEach(function(q){
                if (t.indexOf(q) >= 0) found++;
            });
            if (found===quest.length) elm.addClass("search-successful");
        });      
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't, guess i should mentioned that. This works perfectly! Thankyou (:

Comment: But I think it should not match when you search `æ lle`. Any modification can be done?

Comment: Just realised that yes :( It should still have the word boundary in the start